# ¿Cual es la finalidad de la variable i en este código?

Tags: c#, ordenamiento

//Es el algoritmo de ordenamiento burbuja, y este codigo me lo dieron de la facultad. ¿Cual es la funcion de i? Si siempre vale 0. Gracias.

```
static int[] Burbuja(int[]arreglo){
        int n = arreglo.Length;
        int i = 0;
        bool ordenado = false;
        while ((i<(n-1)) && (!ordenado))
        {
            ordenado = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < (n-i-1); j++)
            {
                if (arreglo[j] > arreglo[j+1])
                {
                    ordenado = false;
                    int swap = arreglo[j];
                    arreglo[j] = arreglo[j+1];
                    arreglo[j+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
        return arreglo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable "i" en realidad está funcionando como una constante que vale cero.
Es para no entrar al bucle en caso que el tamaño del arreglo sea 1 (o menor que 1) dando al arreglo como ordenado.

Comment: Para que sea constante debería tener una sintaxis específica https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants

Comment: @MarcoLedesma ¿Y en el bucle for tiene alguna finalidad? Que dice (n-i-1).